# Setting a ViewController as initial?

Tags: swift

[image]I had followed a tutorial and now I want to take the project further. I moved some things around which seem to work fine. The tutorial didn't use storyboards and it called the initial view in the appDelegate. I had changed that around so it calls my loginVC instead.

```
var window: UIWindow?

var loginVC: UIViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("...", clientKey: "...")

    loginVC = iGameViewController(nibName: "iGameViewController", bundle: nil)

    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    window!.rootViewController = loginVC
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

This only loads a blank white screen. I have a button and a segue on the actual iGameViewController.swift which is connected in the main.storyboard. Is this technically the right way to go about this?

Edit: I added an image to show the main.storyboard - Also in the iGame info settings I have tried to select `Main` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no nib named `"iGameViewController"` so you are ending up with no nib and no interface. What you have is a *storyboard*. And this view controller is marked as the initial view controller (storyboard entry point) in the storyboard already, so it will appear all by itself; you should delete all of that code (except for the parse stuff, and `return true`) and let the storyboard load itself and create the window and the initial view controller *automatically*:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("...", clientKey: "...")
    return true
}
```

NOTE: Be sure that your *Info.plist* specifies that the storyboard `"Main"` is to be used. But if you started with a template, it probably does, so the above code should just work!

Comment: ..Except for the call to set up the Parse application ID.

Comment: @DuncanC Yup, I said, "except for the parse stuff"

Comment: @Swift don't worry, took the parse details out again.

Comment: @matt It says that App delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file. However when I leave it there it still comes up blank...

Comment: It does that, where you say `var window: UIWindow?`. Don't delete that part, obviously. :))))

Comment: It's only blank because you have no interface. Put something into the interface; drag a button into it, for example (into its top left corner) so you can prove to yourself that your view is in fact loading.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: you have switched to Compact/Regular size class (the blue bar at the bottom). That is a _huge_ mistake. Get the heck out of there. Design for Any:Any.

Comment: @matt Okay so it works if I use the storyboard IB just programmed objects aren't showing up. Now I just need to figure out how to set this next part out :D Thanks!